# Is there a way to get all objects of a given type in the UVM hierarchy?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm looking for a way to get all instances of a given `uvm_object` class, preferably filtering with hierarchy/scope and name. Is this achievable in UVM 1.2? I tried the following, which looked like it may work

```
uvm_resource_pool rp = uvm_resource_pool::get();
uvm_resource#(T) _type = new();
uvm_queue#(uvm_resource_base) q;

q = rp.lookup_regex_names(parent.get_full_name(), "*name*", _type);
```

but `q.size()` is always 0. This is admittedly my first exposure to the `uvm_resource_pool` etc, so I'm not even sure if it can be used this way. Is there something wrong with my setup? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking to do?

Comment: There is no way to do things the way you are asking. Only class instances derived from `uvm_component` have hierarchy. Perhaps you can explain what you want to accomplish. See https://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 2):

The `uvm_component` has a method [get_children](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1b/html/files/base/uvm_component-svh.html#uvm_component.get_children). Using this function is straight forward to walk on the component tree starting from the root component.

```sv
function enumerate_components(uvm_component root);
begin
  uvm_component children[$];
  foreach(children[i]) begin
    enumerate_components(children[i]);
  end
end
endfunction
```

You can extend this function to check type with [get_type_name](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/files/base/uvm_object-svh.html#uvm_object.get_type_name)  from the `uvm_object`.

```sv
function enumerate_components(uvm_component root, 
         ref uvm_component components[$], string type_name);
begin
  uvm_component children[$];
  if(root.get_type_name() == type_name) begin
    components.push_back(root);
  end
  foreach(children[i]) begin
    enumerate_components(children[i], components, type_name);
  end
end
endfunction
```

Then you could use it as follows

```sv
uvm_component components[$];
enumerate_components(uvm_root::get(), components, "InterestingComponent");
foreach(components[i]) begin
  // do interesting things
end
```

I did not test it, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I didn’t realize component had this capability.

Comment: The `uvm_registry` does not give you class  _instances_, it only gives the class _types_ registered with the factory.

Comment: Removed the mention to `uvm_registry` as that was not helping, thank you for reviewing :) @dave_59